# Check if the previous month has passed in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Let's say that I have a textbox where the user can input the date
(or can be the value of the current date now using php)
and a "Save" button to perform some action to save the data into my
database to make it simple.

But before it saves the data, I want to perform this action.

1. Check first if the previous month has passed
2. If the previous month has passed, then perform some action to the new month or 
   else perform another action when you are still in this month

This is what I have done so far:

```
<?php
 $currentDate = $_POST['date_input'];

 # Get the previous month
 $sql1 = "SELECT SUBDATE('$currentDate', INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AS prevMonth";
 $result1 = mysql_query($sql1);
 while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
   $prevMonth =  $row1['prevMonth'];                                                            
 }

 # Compare previous date from the current date
 $sql2 = "SELECT DATE('$prevMonth') < DATE('$currentDate') AS compareDate";
 $result2 = mysql_query($sql2);
 while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {
   $result_date =   $row2['compareDate'];
 }

 if($result_date == 1) {    if TRUE
    # This is the new Month
    # Perform some action in this new month

 }  
 else {
    # Your still in this Month
    # Cannot perform this else since the result_date is always TRUE
 } ?>
```

Let's say the current DATE is '2015-01-11' (January 11, 2015)

The previous month would be '2014-12-11' (December 11, 2014) and the condition 
 of $result_date would result to 1 since 2014-12-11 < 2015-01-11 is **TRUE**.

But my problem is, it does not trigger the else statement when Im still on this month
 since the result of comparing the date from previous month to current month will always
 be true ofcourse using the query above.

How can I improve that code to check if I were still on this month and then perform some
 action? Can anybody help me? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using MySQL?
This makes no sense. MySQL is a database.

You can just do it with PHP.

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime('2000-01-20');
$date->sub(new DateInterval('P1M'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
?>
```

For more information see: http://php.net/manual/de/datetime.sub.php